# Increasing MaxContentLength in ExternalContentLibrary config file is giving error

Tags: 2011, publishing

We are using ADAM as our assets repository and have installed Tridion ADAM connector. By default the max content length came as 200MB but now i am trying to increase it size to around 400MB in ExternalContentLibrary.config file and got the below error. Am I missing something?

> An error occurred while trying to resolve URI: ecl:1xxx-xxx.ecl One or
>   more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. The value of this
>   argument must be non-negative. Parameter name: value Actual value was
>   -939524096.
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing Errorcode: 0 User: xxxx
>
> StackTrace Information Details:
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportBindingElement.set_MaxBufferPoolSize(Int64
>   value)    at Tridion.Ecl.Adam.Api.AdamConnector.GetNewSamlClient()
>   at Tridion.Ecl.Adam.Mountpoint..ctor(IEclSession session)    at
>   Tridion.Ecl.Adam.Provider.CreateContext(IEclSession session)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.ContentLibraryViewToContractAddInAdapter.CreateContext(IEclSessionContract
>   session)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Comment: Interesting question. The documentation http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLTridion_ADAMConnector10/task_0EEAE44E6F8C4B4286F0F0B8E00DA135 does not mention a maximum on the content lenght. You filled in 400 as the value in the config is in MBs right? What if you change it back to 200, just to check if there is nothing else which fell over. And just guessing here, but do you exceed any other limits in Tridion configuration files?

Comment: Yes i was filling 400 as the value which is in MB. When changed back to 200 it is working. I have also checked the deployer config file which has 500Mb as the limit and I couldn't see any other Tridion limits being exceeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the max value for this setting is 255.

To increase this maximum a hotfix is needed.

Comment: And to request hotfixes you should contact your friendly Customer Support rep...

Comment: Thanks for the answer as i was banging my head finding the place defining the limit. Would have been easy if this was mentioned in documentation :(